# How to use Google Translate HTML input elements

Tags: javascript, html, translation

Using the following code to try and translate input into HTML input fields and it doesn't seem to work:

```
<body>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function googleTranslateElementInit() {
       new google.translate.TranslateElement({
           pageLanguage: 'en',
           includedLanguages: 'en,ja',
           autoDisplay: false,
           layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
       }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<form>
   First Name: <input type="text" id="firstName" />
   Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastName" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The content of the page is translated OK but not the values in the input fields.  Looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546360/google-translate-tool-does-not-work-on-the-input-type-text-value) solution recommended but I'm unable to make it work.   How do I get values put into input fields to be translated?

Answer (score 1):

Read through the Google Translate API [here](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started), but I'll also try and explain it a bit.

First of all the Google API requires a registered key with each query. Look on the API page to see how to aqcuire that key.

Next, if you look to the API page it will give you a default url to query like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?{paramaters}
```

An example to translate 'hello' from english to spanish would be:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key={INSERT-YOUR-KEY}&source=en&target=es&q=hello
```

to pass on the input from a form, you will need to use PHP to plug your information into your google translate query string.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Cameronn, Unfortunately this won't work for me as I'm unable to pay for the service.  Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

I made something like this. It works form me. I haven't use any API.

create input like this scheme:

```
﻿<value for="1" style="display:none">Asia,Southern Asia</value>
<input contenteditable="true" name="1" type="text" placeholder="Asia,Southern Asia" value="Asia,Southern Asia">
```

translate your page with Google translate plug. Then, call this function

```
function translateInput(){
    for(i=0; i<$('input').length; i++){
            $('input').eq(i).val($('value').eq(i).text());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let Me give You one more simple solution

html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'ar', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}




$('#confirmTraslate').click(function(){

   $('.translated-element').each(function(){
      id=$(this).data('label-for');
      $('#'+id).val( $(this).text() );
   });

});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
               <div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<div class="form-group">
                              <label>Address</label>
                              <input class="form-control" id="consignee_address_line1" name="consignee_address_line1" value="القطيف - حي الشاطي
شارع ابي ذر الغفاريالقطيفSaudi Arabia" type="text">
                              <label class="translated-element" data-label-for="consignee_address_line1">القطيف - حي الشاطي
شارع ابي ذر الغفاريالقطيفSaudi Arabia</label>
                           </div>
```