# What is the best practice to support multiple languages for the descriptions of products?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, localization, internationalization

I am writing a ASP.Net Core 2.2 Web Api and now I got the request to support multiple languages (de, en) for the description of our products. What is the best practice for this scenario?

I now read a lot about resx files and this documentation 2 times: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2, but then I also read this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10533904/11049948), which says I should just include multiple columns (for each language) for the descriptions in my database.

Now what is the best practice, to

1. Store the descriptions in multiple languages
2. Get the right Description from a request

**To clarify the question:**

By products are meant usual products (like for example clothes). In the frontend (Angular), Admins should be able to edit/create products => Products are dynamic.
I haven't really understood when to use resx files (Only for static content, which is not the case here?). Is it now best practice to have those 2 columns in the Product table: Description_DE, Description_EN? What would I do with more than 2 languages?

I hope this clarifies the question...

Comment: By products, you mean something like items in a shopping cart, for example?

Comment: Which did you try, where you having problems, where are you stuck and why do you think one is better than the other? Please have a read on [What's On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based may be put on hold by the community until they are improved_  and you are essentially asking for a opinions

Comment: I edited the question to clarify the details.

Comment: Store in different table : `Table Description { id_product, id_language, Description, isDefault }` to store multiple description for a product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table for the description of products ( instead of a varchar column ).

For the `products` table :

```
    |--------------|----------------|------------------------|
    |ProductId     | DescriptionId  |Price                   |
    |--------------|----------------|------------------------|
    |  1           | 20             | 150.00                 |
    |  2           | 20             | 370.00                 |
```

For the new table of `Description`:

```
    |--------------|------------|------------------------|
    |DescriptionId | LanguageId |Label                   |
    |------------- | -----------|------------------------|
    |  20          | 1          | This is English bla bla|
    |  20          | 2          | das ist en deutsch bla |
```

`Language` also is a Table .

Using this approach , you can manage many language as you want , and when you want to get the data ,you pass the `languageId` of the user .

So if you want to get the details of product 1 :

```
SELECT * from product p 
INNER JOIN Description d 
ON p.descriptionId = d.descriptionId
WHERE p.podouctId = 1 and d.languageId = 2 -- DE Desciption
```